# primes of the forms $...54321012345...$ and $...543212345...$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm looking for primes formed from concatenating the **first $n$ natural numbers** in these following manners:

- $(n)(n-1)(n-2)\cdots54321012345\cdots(n-2)(n-1)(n)$
- $(n)(n-1)(n-2)\cdots543212345\cdots(n-2)(n-1)(n)$
- I have checked both of them for n up to $600$, but the only primes I've found are $101$ and $131211109876543212345678910111213$, which is n=$1$, and n=$13$ respectively. Are there anymore primes of these forms besides those two (n=$1$, n=$13$)?

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

Your version that excludes 0 is problem 19 from https://fs.unm.edu/OPNS.pdf :
[image]

The sequence of such numbers is https://oeis.org/A007942
And $a(13)$ is the only prime of this form known up to $n \leq 1530$