# Prime numbers from listing the first natural numbers in $2$ directions

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Consider prime numbers formed from concatenating the **first $n$ natural numbers** in these ways:

- $(n)(n-1)\cdots765432101234567\cdots(n-1)(n)$
- $(n)(n-1)\cdots7654321234567\cdots(n-1)(n)$

I've checked both of them for $n$ up to $800$,but the only primes I got are $101$ and $131211109876543212345678910111213$, which are of indices of $n=1$ and $n=13$ respectively. Could you find the next primes of those forms after $n=1$; $n=13$?

Comment: What exactly is the challenge here? In addition, any particular reason for choosing base $10$ over other bases?

Comment: @barakmanos, I have already found some primes in other bases, but here we are interested in base10 only : )

Comment: The same question was [asked yesterday](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512313/primes-of-the-forms-54321012345-and-543212345).